# General structure for executing system commands from x86-64 assembly (NASM)?

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I am trying to make some basic system calls in assembly (x86-64 in NASM on OSX), but have so far been unsuccessful.

The only examples I have seen on the web so far are for reading from stdin or writing to stdout, such as this:

```
global main
section .text

main:
  call write

write:
  mov rax, 0x2000004
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rsi, message
  mov rdx, length
  syscall

section .data
message: db 'Hello, world!', 0xa
length: equ $ - message
```

However, when I try to use that same pattern to make another system call, it doesn't work (it's saying `Bus error: 10`):

```
global main
section .text

main:
  call mkdir

mkdir:
  mov rax, 0x2000136 ; mkdir system command number
  mov rdi, rax ; point destination to system command
  mov rsi, directory ; first argument
  mov rdx, 755 ; second argument
  syscall

section .data
directory: db 'tmp', 0xa
```

What is the general structure for calling system commands (on OSX in NASM ideally)?

Basically what it seems like you're supposed to do is find your desired system call in here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.3.12/bsd/kern/syscalls.master. So the "write" one looks like this:

```
4   AUE_NULL    ALL { user_ssize_t write(int fd, user_addr_t cbuf, user_size_t nbyte); }
```

That is saying:

- system call number: 4
- number of arguments: 3 (file descriptor, memory address to string/buffer, length of buffer)

So I was beginning to think the general pattern was this:

```
rax: system call number
rdi: maybe? point to system call ("destination index"), but why the `1` in the write example?
rsi: first argument to system call ("source index", the string in this case)
rdx: second argument to system call
rcx: third argument (if necessary, but not in the system write case)
```

So then it's like you could do a direct mapping of any of the system commands. So `mkdir`:

```
136 AUE_MKDIR ALL { int mkdir(user_addr_t path, int mode); }
```

would be translated to:

```
rax: 0x20000136 ; 136 + 20000000
rdi: i dunno, maybe `rax`?
rsi: directory (first argument)
rdx: 755 (mode, second argument)
```

But yeah, that doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? What is the general pattern of how to do this so I can test it out on any of the other system commands in [syscalls.master](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.3.12/bsd/kern/syscalls.master)? Can you describe the role the different registers play here too? That would help clarify a lot I think.

Comment: I'm not going to pretend to know anything about OSX but '1' in the write call is probably the file descriptor for stdout. That tells me that rdi is the first param which should be directory and rsi is the second which should be mode. If I'm wrong let me know and I'll shut up.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea, how do you figure that stuff out? (Like is there a list of file descriptor values for different OSes or something?)

Comment: Posix standard stdout = 1, stderr = 2, stdin = 0. [http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/unistd.h.html](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/unistd.h.html).

Answer (score 4):

I believe OSX is following the standard SYSV ABI calling convention, at least your example certainly looks like that. Arguments go in the registers `RDI`, `RSI`, `RDX`, `R10`, `R8`, and `R9`, in order. System call number goes into `RAX`.

Let's look at `write`: `int fd, user_addr_t cbuf, user_size_t nbyte`
The assembly:

```
mov rdi, 1       ; fd = 1 = stdout 
mov rsi, message ; cbuf
mov rdx, length  ; nbyte
```

Now, for `mkdir`: `user_addr_t path, int mode`
Obviously you need to put `path` into `rdi` and `mode` into `rsi`.

```
mkdir:
  mov rax, 0x2000136 ; mkdir system command number
  mov rdi, directory ; first argument
  mov rsi, 0x1ED     ; second argument, 0x1ED = 755 octal
  syscall
  ret
```

Note you need `ret` and the end of `mkdir` subroutine, and you also need one so your `main` doesn't fall through into `mkdir`. Furthermore, you should probably use `lea` to load the `directory` argument, and use `RIP`-relative addressing, such as `lea rdi, [rel directory]`.

Comment: Hmm, now the bus error goes away, but I don't see the directory generated. Is there anything else wrong? https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/a84ca2d67e98a4be1788

Comment: You need to terminate your directory name with a `0` not `0xa` (line feed).

Comment: Doesn't seem do work either :/ How do you know what those values should be? (Is there some documentation for that? Haven't found anything describing how that last argument to `db` works yet).

Comment: Strings in C and system calls are zero terminated. You might be having a different problem. Check the return value in `rax` after the syscall (that's an error code). Also check that all of the parent directories exist, since `mkdir` will only create the final component.

Comment: K, gonna have to dig into that then. All of the parent directories exist, so that shouldn't be a problem. I can do `mkdir tmp` no problem. Will have to figure out how to check the return value in `rax`, don't know how to debug that stuff yet, any suggestions?

Comment: Apparently `dtruss` is the os x equivalent of `strace`, so run your program through that. It should log what system call you actually invoke, what arguments you pass and what the result is.

Answer (score 2):

You've got it almost right: You need 0x88 (dec 136) for the syscall number. The syscalls in syscall.master are in decimal. You ended up calling getsid (which is syscall 310).

For arguments, don't use syscalls.master since that gives you the kernel perspective which is a tad skewed (when it comes to argument names). You should use /usr/include/unistd.h for the prototypes, and usr/inclunde/sys/syscall.h for the numbers. syscalls.master comes in handy only in cases where the syscalls aren't exported to these files, and those are cases where the master files says NO_SYSCALL_STUB.

As for the ABI, it's the same as System V AMD64 ABI. http://people.freebsd.org/~obrien/amd64-elf-abi.pdf

You can see the system calls as libsystem does them:

```
otool -tV /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib  | more 
# seek to /^_mkdir:
_mkdir:
0000000000012dfc        movl    $0x2000088, %eax
0000000000012e01        movq    %rcx, %r10
0000000000012e04        syscall
0000000000012e06        jae     0x12e0d
0000000000012e08        jmpq    cerror_nocancel
0000000000012e0d        ret
0000000000012e0e        nop
0000000000012e0f        nop
```

All the system calls essentially have the structure:

1. Arguments by this point have been put in RDI,RSI,... as per above
   ABI
2. The system call # is loaded into EAX. The 0x2 implies POSIX
   syscall. 0x1 would be a Mach Trap, 0x3 - arch specific, 0x4 -
   Diagnostic syscalls
3. rcx saved into r10
4. syscall gets executed

   << kernel portion occurs, wherein execution goes into kernel mode through trap,
           and the value of eax is used to i) get to system call table and ii) branch to  correct 
           system call   >>

   5. kernel mode returns to user mode, past the syscall instruction
   6. EAX now holds the syscall return value, so
      that "jae" means if the syscall return value is >=0 - i.e. ok -
      continue to the "ret" and return to the user
   7. if not, jump to
      cerror_nocancel which loads the value of errno and returns the -1 to
      the user.

Answer (score 1):

The `Bus error: 10` error appears to be caused by an incorrect syscall number and no exit syscall.

```
; nasm -f macho64 mkdir.asm && ld -o mkdir mkdir.o && ./mkdir

%define SYSCALL_MKDIR 0x2000088
%define SYSCALL_EXIT  0x2000001

global start

section .text
start:
  call mkdir
  call exit
  ret

mkdir:
  mov rax, SYSCALL_MKDIR
  mov rdi, directory
  mov rsi, 0x1ED
  syscall

exit:
  mov rax, SYSCALL_EXIT
  mov rdi, 0
  syscall

section .data
directory: db 'tmp', 0
```

Summary of changes to the original code:

- Renaming the `main` symbol to `start`
- Changing the mkdir syscall number from `0x2000136` to `0x2000088`
- Changing the registry assignments
- Changing the `0xa` character to `0` in the directory variable (works without but results in an incorrect filename)

### NASM

I also had to install version 2.10.09 of `nasm`:

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew/c1616860c8697ffed8887cae8088ab39141f0308/Library/Formula/nasm.rb
brew switch nasm 2.10.09
```

This was due to:

- No `nacho64` support in `/usr/bin/nasm`
- Latest brew version (2.11.08) results in this error: `fatal: No section for index 2 offset 0 found`

Comment: The *fatal: No section for index 2 offset 0 found* is related to a documented [bug](http://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392306) specifically with 2.11.08. We've been dealing with issues on SO about it for a while.